# Smooth interpolation with discontinuities, irregular grid and different densities.

Tags: interpolation

What would be an appropriate interpolation method that does some smoothing (similar to splines), allows for unknown (relatively big) discontinuities, can be run on a dataset in an irregular grid and with an equally irregular density of points (ie: if X is the date, we can have 20 points on one day and only 5 or even none on the next day).

Solutions such as a simple spline do not work very well, as the discontinuities really affect in a bad way the interpolation [(Splines on interpolation with discontinuities)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EyUh.png).

Total variation based interpolation may be a good solution, but I have the feeling that random googling will not give me the optimal solution of my problem: an expert opinion would be more efficient than the hours I have spent looking at interpolation research that does not exactly fit my problem.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hi Jose Carlos. I have added a bit more of detail to the answer. As I state there, I have already spent several hours looking for a good answer, but without expert guidance, it is a blind search as I have no way of knowing if the interpolation methods I find are the best fit for my problem.

Comment: It looks better now.